# Adding options to a Select control in IE8/IE9

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, html4

I have an iframe with a select control in it that I would like to add some options to. I am able to add options to the select inside the iframe using IE10+, Firefox, and Chrome, but my current solution does not work for IE8 and IE9.

I would like to find a way to add options to my select control. I have tried several solutions proposed on other stack overflow questions, but they do not seem to be working for me.

Here is the relevant part of my HTML view:

```
<!-- In the iframe -->
 <div>
   <div class="inline-block">SelectSomething: </div>
   <select name="select-dialog" id="select-dialog" class="inline-block"></select>
</div>
```

Here is a snippet of my javascript code that tries to add options to the select control above:

```
// Grab select from iframe
var dialogSelect = document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('select-dialog');

var isIE8 = (isIE && getIEVersion() === 8);

if (isIE8)
{
  dialogSelect.innerHTML = '';

  // Attempt 1
  var opt = new Option();
  opt.innerHTML = 'Kobe';
  opt.value = 'BlackMamba';

  var opt2 = new Option();
  opt2.innerHTML = 'RKelly';
  opt2.value = 'PiedPiper';

  dialogSelect.appendChild(opt);
  dialogSelect.appendChild(opt2);

  // Attempt 2
  // var opt = dialogSatelliteSelect.options;
  // opt[0] = new Option('Kobe', 'BlackMamba');
  // opt[1] = new Option('R Kelly', 'PiedPiper');

  console.log('innerHTML: ' + dialogSelect.innerHTML);
}
else
{
  // The select is not populated with options in IE8 and IE9. This works with other browsers
  dialogSelect.innerHTML = getOptions();
}
```

The console output for both attempts 1 and 2 are:

```
innerHTML: <OPTION value=BlackMamba selected>Kobe</OPTION><OPTION value=PiedPiper>RKelly</OPTION>
```

Even though the innerHTML contains the options I have created, I cannot select them using IE8/IE9. The drop down appears blank with nothing selected.

**What do I need to do to have these options display in my select control? Is there some special step I need to take with IE8 to show the current options?**

Comment: Please don't include partial code, aim toward always providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Will do. I will work to make a small test app that highlights my issue. Thanks for the guidance